# Samsung account crashes on S3

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-gear-vr

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 LTE.  I've been trying to use it with a Samsung Gear S3 Classic.  The phone and watch can find each other, but whenever I attempt to push an app or a watchface from the phone to the watch, I get the message

> Unfortunately, Samsung account has stopped

I have seen this message for a little while now (whenever I restart the phone) but I have largely ignored it because the phone still operated correctly.  However, now it seems like it prevents the Samsung Gear app from installing items to the watch.

I have found some items that talk about updating the firmware.  I've downloaded Kies 3 (version 2.6.4.17113_1) and that refuses to do anything with my phone (which is running Android 4.4.4).   I've downloaded Smart Switch.  Which will actually connect to my phone and I've been able to back it up.  But it thinks the phone is running the latest firmware version.  In fact, my phone thinks that too when I check it directly on the phone.

I just would like to get Samsung Gear to install items on the watch, so it's pretty frustrating.  If anyone knows how to get Gear to work with this phone, I would truly appreciate any help.

I have read that this is related to an incomplete Samsung account.  I never had one.  I did create one online with the hope to add it to the phone.  However, attempts to add the Samsung account causes the same crash message,

Details:

- Phone Model Number: GT-19305
- Android Version: 4.4.4
- Android Security Patch Level: 2016-01-01
- Baseband Version: 19305XXUFPA1
- Kernel Version: 3.0.31-6850576
- Build Number: KTU84P.19305XXUFPA1
- SE for Android Status: Enforcing SEPF_GT-19305_4.4.4_0050

Comment: Well, that's a shame.  I had asked this question on Samsung's community (https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S-Phones/bd-p/GalaxyS) and it was removed.  I guess I was hoping for actual support from them.

Comment: I've added it a second time.  See if they answer this time (https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S-Phones/Samsung-account-constantly-crashes-on-S3/m-p/239705#M42859)